# Not properly validating on Add-to-Cart. Can still purchase more stock than in inventory

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

After banging my head against the wall I have finally managed to reduce my stock quantity based on the value in a custom field.

The issue I am having now is that it isn't properly validating (second part). Despite there only being say 20 in stock, I am still able to add 50 to the cart and checkout (leaving my inventory in the negative). I'd preferably like to add-to-cart using AJAX, but for now, I just want to get this validation working. Any insight?

```
// reduce stock based on custom field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 ); 
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item )  
{
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    $term_name = $product->get_meta( 'custom_field', true );

    // 'pa_weight' attribute value is "15 grams" - keep only the numbers
    $quantity_grams = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);

    // new quantity
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity_grams ) && $quantity_grams != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity_grams;

    return $quantity;
}

// check out of stock using custom field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight' );
function woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight() 
{
    // get product id
    if (isset($_REQUEST["add-to-cart"])) {
        $productid = (int)$_REQUEST["add-to-cart"];
    } else {
        $productid = null;
    }

    // get quantity
    if (isset($_REQUEST["quantity"])) {
        $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST["quantity"];
    } else {
        $quantity = 1;
    }

    // get weight of selected attribute
    if (isset($_REQUEST["custom_field"])) {
        $weight = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $_REQUEST["custom_field"]);
    } else {
        $weight = null;
    }

    // comparing stock
    if($productid && $weight)
    {
        $product = wc_get_product($productid);
        $productstock = (int)$product->get_stock_quantity();

        if(($weight * $quantity) > $productstock)
        {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'You cannot add that amount of "%1$s" to the cart because there is not enough stock (%2$s remaining).', $product->get_title(), $productstock ), 'error' );
            return;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```